# Nginx Cannot Find OpenSSL Development Headers

Tags: macos, nginx, openssl, homebrew

When I run: `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` on my Mac to install nginx, the terminal prints:

```
Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
  Found: no
```

But I am certain I have openssl installed. `which openssl` returns `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl` and `/usr/local/openssl/bin:` is the first entry in my $PATH. My questions are:

- Are the OpenSSL development headers included with the regular openssl install through homebrew?
- If they aren't, where should I download them from?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: To answer your questions... (1) No, the development packages are not usually installed with the utilities. (2) Your distro normally provides them by way of a [`libssl-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libssl-dev) or `libssl-devel` package. You should probably ask about Homebrew package management on another forum, like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is redundant with http://superuser.com/questions/982960/nginx-cannot-find-openssl-development-headers, which has been solved by the OP

Comment: You may pass options to `configure` to help locate your openssl dev files. `--with-cc-opt="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include" --with-ld-opt="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`. You have to tell passenger to let you customize the Nginx installation (when it asks you) and you will have the possibility to provide "Extra arguments to pass to configure script".

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If `brew link openssl --force` gives you this message:

Warning: Refusing to link: openssl Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl. Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.: `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Try this:

```
$ brew doctor (now fix anything that it tells you to fix)
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
```

Now let's install it:

```
$ brew install openssl
```

And now we'll link it into our public area so you don't have to figure out the magic environment variable to set while building your favorite OpenSSL-backed library:

```
$ cd /usr/local/include
$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

All done!  Enjoy

Comment: This should be the answer! :D

Comment: Accepted answer is outdated.

Answer (score 18):

If you are on Mac OS X El Capitan, Apple doesn't include openssl  any more because of security problems openssl had, I have similar problem installing Passenger. brew just installs openssl itself without development headers.

If you are on an older version of Mac OS X than El Capitan, you can use:
`xcode-select --install` 
which installs openssl development headers as well.

**EDIT:**

Updating brew and installing openssl and force linking openssl to brew version solved my problem:

```
$ brew update 
$ which openssl  
/usr/bin/openssl 
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force 
$ which openssl 
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Comment: I tried uninstalling with homebrew then reinstalling so that the terminal points to /usr/local/bin/openssl. But I still have the development headers marked as missing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If brew link openssl --force does not work anymore, try this link. https://solitum.net/openssl-os-x-el-capitan-and-brew/ Worked for me.

Comment: `$ brew link openssl --force 
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
`

Comment: After running all those commands, `which openssl` resulted in `/usr/bin/openssl` for me, not `/usr/local/bin/openssl` (on SierraOS).

Comment: Curious: a) osx doesn't use openssl because of security b) osx doesn't include openssl. Is it (a) or (b) or (both) ?