# Compiling Hadoop Native libs from source on mac os

Tags: java, macos, maven, hadoop, cmake

I'm strugling with compiling of latest Hadoop from source with next exception:

```
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ hadoop-pipes ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) @ hadoop-pipes ---
[INFO] Running cmake /Users/romeo/Repository/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/src -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64 -G Unix Makefiles
[INFO] with extra environment variables {}
[WARNING] CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
[WARNING]   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
[WARNING]   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
[WARNING] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[WARNING]   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
[WARNING]   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:385 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
[WARNING]   CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]
[WARNING] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[WARNING] See also "/Users/romeo/Repository/hadoop/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/target/native/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.920 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  0.939 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.191 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  2.458 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.170 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  2.170 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  6.001 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  2.502 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  7.454 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  4.214 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [ 56.405 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  5.317 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [  7.725 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.044 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SUCCESS [ 15.292 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SUCCESS [ 39.539 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client ................... SUCCESS [  2.075 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SUCCESS [ 22.573 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SUCCESS [  3.311 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SUCCESS [  0.049 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................. SUCCESS [  0.044 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................. SUCCESS [  8.825 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common .......................... SUCCESS [ 22.424 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server .......................... SUCCESS [  0.030 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common ................... SUCCESS [  5.927 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager ..................... SUCCESS [  8.990 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ....................... SUCCESS [  2.795 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ....... SUCCESS [  4.752 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service ................ SUCCESS [  7.784 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................. SUCCESS [ 14.938 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests .................... SUCCESS [  1.469 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client .......................... SUCCESS [  4.031 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager .............. SUCCESS [  2.766 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Plugin Storage ......... SUCCESS [  2.808 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service HBase tests .... SUCCESS [  2.918 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications .................... SUCCESS [  0.041 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ................ SUCCESS [  2.676 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher ........... SUCCESS [  2.113 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ............................ SUCCESS [  0.043 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ........................ SUCCESS [  3.960 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN UI .............................. SUCCESS [  0.029 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ......................... SUCCESS [  6.991 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client ..................... SUCCESS [  0.138 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ....................... SUCCESS [ 14.384 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common ..................... SUCCESS [ 12.110 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle .................... SUCCESS [  3.040 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ........................ SUCCESS [  6.127 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer .............. SUCCESS [  4.264 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient .................. SUCCESS [  3.597 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ...... SUCCESS [  1.715 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce NativeTask ................. SUCCESS [  6.028 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SUCCESS [  4.248 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ............................ SUCCESS [  3.660 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SUCCESS [  3.836 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SUCCESS [  3.238 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SUCCESS [  1.621 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archive Logs ......................... SUCCESS [  2.315 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SUCCESS [  4.120 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SUCCESS [  2.797 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SUCCESS [  1.888 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SUCCESS [  1.628 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ FAILURE [  0.533 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Aliyun OSS support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure Data Lake support .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Kafka Library support ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-26T07:18:34+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 146M/857M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-pipes: CMake failed with error code 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

As you can see from the output it fails at 'Apache Hadoop Pipes' because of unresolved dependency 'Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins'. However, Maven plugins were done with SUCCESS status:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
    ... 30 more
[ERROR]
```

Any advice or hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE1: Installing OpenSSL did resolve the main issue:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Hadoop Pipes 3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:jar:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

UPDATE2: After performing `mvn install`  getting new exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-pipes: CMake failed with error code 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-pipes: CMake failed with error code 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing `hadoop-maven-plugin` can be done by `mvn install` first.

```
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ mvn package -Pdist -Pnative -Dtar -DskipTests
```

The dependencies detail is described in [BUILDING.txt](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt).

Or if you have docker environment, [`start-build-env.sh`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/start-build-env.sh) creates docker container on which Hadoop can be build.

```
$ cd hadoop
$ ./start-build-env.sh # Automatically login
```

Since all necessary dependencies are already installed in this container, you can build Hadoop package including native inside this container.

Comment: Thank you. But didn't help me much. :)
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-pipes: CMake failed with error code 1 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Did you installed CMake in your MacOSX? Or how about using `start-build-env.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511474/877031)

The problem was connected with OpenSSL package. By default, it does not include dev headers.