# Apache-Hadoop-Common failing to compile: Error running javah command

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I am trying to create a Hadoop cluster by following this guide:
https://data.andyburgin.co.uk/post/157450047463/running-hue-on-a-raspberry-pi-hadoop-cluster

The master node I am trying to configure is a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB with Raspbian OS installed.

After running:

```
sudo mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar
```

The compiler fails at hadoop-common
I am using hadoop build 3.2.0 but otherwise following the directions as close as possible.
Below is where I am failing:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Apache Hadoop Main 3.2.0:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  2.921 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  3.715 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  3.370 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  6.031 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  1.234 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  3.917 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [ 12.101 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  5.393 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [ 18.551 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  7.393 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [ 11.293 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-RBF ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Plugin Storage ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Backend ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Common .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Client .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Servers ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Server 1.2  SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase tests ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Router .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Services ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Services Core ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Services API .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Image Generation Tool ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Yet Another Learning Platform ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN UI .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce NativeTask ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Uploader ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archive Logs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Kafka Library support ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Aliyun OSS support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Aggregator .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Resource Estimator Service ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure Data Lake support .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client API ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Runtime ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Invariants .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Test Minicluster .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Invariants for Test . SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Integration Tests ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Modules ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage Project ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-03T19:44:11-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-8:javah (default) on project hadoop-common: Error running javah command: Error executing command line. Exit code:2 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-8:javah (default) on project hadoop-common: Error running javah command
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error running javah command
at org.codehaus.mojo.natives.plugin.NativeJavahMojo.execute (NativeJavahMojo.java:226)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.natives.NativeBuildException: Error executing command line. Exit code:2
at org.codehaus.mojo.natives.util.CommandLineUtil.execute (CommandLineUtil.java:34)
at org.codehaus.mojo.natives.javah.JavahExecutable.compile (JavahExecutable.java:46)
at org.codehaus.mojo.natives.plugin.NativeJavahMojo.execute (NativeJavahMojo.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

I've set the following in ~/.bashrc :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:jre/bin/java::")  
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.0-src
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop- hdfs/src/main/conf
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

I changed the java version to:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1+rpi1-b01)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.212-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am not sure how to fix this javah error. I've tried changing the path to a shorter path (/.m2/repository) as that was a suggestion for an Error 127.

Any ideas? Here is the full error log from the compilation:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kre4HInwWQlACG-u6tSOy_X5EHihuw5Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you installed `cmake`?

Comment: Yes cmake is installed.    

    `cmake version 3.13.4`

`CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).`

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur when path is too long.

To fix this problem and avoid Maven build issues like *'The command line is too long.'*, try to create a symbolic link to point to the folder `.m2\repository` to another folder with shorter path (ex: `C:\mrepo`) by executing this command:

```
mklink /J C:\mrepo C:\Users\your_user_name\.m2\repository
```

And then update `settings.xml` file (located in `%MAVEN_HOME%/conf/setting.xml`) to configure local repository path:

```
<localRepository>C:\mrepo</localRepository>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed this?
`cmake` `gcc9` `boost`

Have you tried building it this way?

```bash
mvn clean install -DskipTests
mvn package -Pdist -Pnative -Dtar -DskipTests
```

*More information:*

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40816478/3182598
2. https://www.mail-archive.com/user@hadoop.apache.org/msg24235.html